# Why object(root) class does not clashes multiple inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, oop

As we know .Net does not support multiple inheritance. Thus we can only inherit only one class. But every class by default inherits 'object' class. so why not error occurs when I inherit any other class.

For example A- Base class, B- Derived Class. When I use **B:A** , implicitly object class also get inherited as( I think) **B:A,Object** . How can it be possible if .Net does not support multiple inheritance.

Comment: Think of Object as the grand parent of every other class. class A is the child, class B is the grand child. B has only 1 parent class which is A & object is B's grand parent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it's not like that - there's only one inheritance chain, which would be:

```
__________
| Object |
----------
    ^
    |
__________
|   A    |
----------
    ^
    |
__________
|   B    |
----------
```

Any one class only has one direct base class, but the inheritance chain of classes can be long.

As an example of why this *isn't* the same as `B` inheriting directly from `A`, if `A` overrides `ToString`, there's no way of `B` calling the original implementation of `Object.ToString()` - it can *only* call `A`'s version (and override `ToString` itself, of course).

Answer (score 3):

It's simple, the declared class *only* inherits from `object` if it does not inherit from another class. What the compiler does is that it effectively changes

```
public class MyBaseLessClass
{
}
```

to

```
public class MyBaseLessClass : object
{
}
```

so that each and every class has *exactly one* class it inherits from. (a bit like the [barber paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_shaves_the_barber) :))